# my game is shoot the " * " in the car by a gun

Tags: python-3.x

```
import time
from threading import Thread
# Make a car for shoot.
car = ["""
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t     ______
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t ___/*     \__
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t|_____________|
\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t o          o
"""]
enemy = car[0]
space = " " * 80
ospace = " " * 40
newspace = space + enemy
# Make a gun for shoot.
gun = ["""
\t\t __
\t\t|  |\ 
\t\t|  ||
\t\t|  ||
\t\t|  ||
\t\t|  ||
\t\t|  ||
\t\t|  ||
\t\t|  | \ 
\t\t–––-\ \ 
\t\t\    \ |
\t\t \    \|
\t\t  -----
"""]
hawk = gun[0]
place = ospace + hawk
b = 1
def check():
   time.sleep(1)
   if answer != None:
      return
for x in range(100):
   print(str(newspace))
   for a in range(3):
       print()
   print(str(place))
   # if the player doesn't  shoot after 1 second, the game continue
   Thread(target = check).start()
   answer = input("Enter for shoot: ")
   # if the player shoot, the game end. 
   if anwser != None:
      break
   # If the player doesn't shoot, the car continue to go.
   else:    
      newspace = space + "\b" * b + enemy
   b += 8
```

Here's the error I get:

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 923, in _bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()
>     File    "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py",        line 871, in run
>        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
>        File "thu3.py", line 34, in check
>         if answer != None:
>        NameError: name 'answer' is not defined
>        """

Comment: This is pretty explicit: `name 'answer' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in the line `if anwser != None:` : `anwser` != `answer`